# Bearer token is missing in my postman

Tags: magento2, rest-api, postman

I am using Postman to test all Magento API.
In one machine I was unable to find the Authentication Type: Bearer

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use like this also

Authorization Bearer yourtoken